# What is the difference between "Iterables" and "Iterators"?

Tags: guava

I'm a newbie with google guava. I don't know when we should use "Iterables" or "Iterators". Could you help me explain them?

Comment: Do you know the difference between core Java [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) and [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Iterables):

> As a result, many of the operations you might expect to see supported
>   for all collections can be found in `Iterables`. Additionally, most
>   `Iterables` methods have a corresponding version in `Iterators` that
>   accepts the raw iterator.

Many methods in `Iterables` call the coresponsding methods in `Iterators`.
p-code:

```
Iterables.operation(Iterables it){
  if(it is-a Collection)
    return it.operation();
  else
    return Iterators.operation(it.iterator());
}
```